# How can I keep the navigation bar at the top of the screen when scrolling?

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin

I'm working on an iPad app in Xamarin that (among other things) will download PDFs from a file system and show them in a webview. When scrolling through the webview to read a PDF, I've been asked to keep the navigation bar at the top of the screen. It currently goes away once the user has scrolled down at all.

I searched for how to do this and for a question like this here, but did not find anything related to mobile development. I would think this is something others have tried, but perhaps this goes against Apple guidelines? If anyone has found something stating that, I'll take that as an answer or any sample code of an implementation of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can create custom uiview that look like navigation bar above the scroll view

Comment: Is the "navigation bar" in side the web view or PDF?  Can you show what it looks like before and after the user scrolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `UIVIew` and add there `navigationBar`. Under you `navBar` add `webView`. That's all.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wound up doing.